# Architecture and implementation of a de-centralised web service

Tags: design, architecture, server, distributed-system

I'm a web programmer with several years of experience in RoR and node.js. I have a project idea that is quite big and I need some input in how it can be achieved.

I heard of the Diaspora project, and how it is de-centralised. In a way, which I don't really get, anyone can setup an instance of the app and connect it to the other instances, and the contents can be shared from any instance.

I want to do something similar: without getting into details here, I basically want a single site or service, where the front-end looks for the end user like a single thing, but the content is actually hosted by anyone who sets up a server.

How could such a thing be built? Would it even scale? I want something like an unified front-end with a single search and user account, but the bulk of byte-heavy data is hosted on the servers of their owners.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask. I just don't know where else I can ask for input on this.

Comment: The biggest problems you'll have to solve are how the peers discover and trust each other. Once this is solved, it is much like a centralized system that runs on multiple nodes. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes, basically that: What is the best way to have the peers connect and trust.

Comment: Do I understand your requirements correctly that you want the data to be decentralised but not the node that receives the request?

Comment: @null Yes. However, not all the data will be de-centralised, only things like images, audio, the like.

Comment: a bit like the world wide web?